# Trigonometric identity $\sin (n\arccos x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $n\in{\mathbb{N}}.$ Prove that

$$\sin\Big(n\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\Big)=(-1)^{n+1}\sin\Big(n\Big(\arctan x +\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)\Big),$$ for all $n\in{\mathbb{N}}.$

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $\arcsin\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=y\implies0<y\le\dfrac\pi2$

and $\sin y=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\implies\cot y=|x|$ as $\cot y\not<0$

$\implies y=$arccot$(|x|)=\dfrac\pi2-\arctan(|x|)$

Where as $\arctan x-\dfrac\pi2=-$arccot$(x)$

As $\sin(-u)=-\sin u$
$$\implies(-1)^{n+1}\sin\Big(n\Big(\arctan x -\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)\Big)=(-1)^n\sin\left(n\text{arccot}(x)\right)$$

As $0<$arccot$(x)<\pi,$

arccot$(x)=\begin{cases} \arcsin\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}} &\mbox{if } x\ge0 \\ 
\pi-\arcsin\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}} & \mbox{if } x<0 \end{cases}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: How did you write arccot ? I ran into an error when I tried it.

Comment: @AritraDas, Please click on edit link on my answer :)

Comment: Thanks. Nice trick. I had started using $\cot^{-1}$ myself.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with $n=1$

$$\phi=\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Which is equivalent to $$\sin\phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Now you can draw this angle in a triangle:

[image]

From the right hand site define the other angle as
$$\psi = \arctan x+\frac\pi2$$
Which can be simplified to
$$\tan(\psi-\frac\pi 2)=x=-\cot\psi$$

Using the geometric definition you can see that $\phi=-\psi$. With $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$ you get the identity of your assumption (for $n=1$) that
$$\sin\Big(\phi\Big)=-1\sin\Big(\psi\Big)$$

#### For $n\neq 1$

$$\sin\Big(n\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\Big)=(-1)^{n+1}\sin\Big(n\Big(\arctan x -\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)\Big)$$

Sorry either I made a mistake above or $(-1)^{n+1}$ in your formula does not make any sense to me...

Comment: Question has been changed. Have a look.

Comment: I apologize for the mistake. Thank you Aritra Das!

Comment: $\pm\frac \pi 2$ does not influence  very much.

Comment: I updated these lines